# FieldCollapsing in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, lucene.net

I tried with Field Collapsing in Solr 3.5 and with Standard request handler I'm able to get the collapsed/grouped response but when tried hitting an custom request handler, im not able to see the grouping results. Please let me know whether I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the `collapse` search component like -
`<searchComponent name="collapse" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.CollapseComponent" />`
and then include it in your request handler.

Have a look at the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsingUncommitted).

Comment: Is collapsing the same as grouping, I need to achieve grouping http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing